# Adding elements to a list when specific pattern is found

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, file

When reading the file, I would like my script to sum lines following the specific pattern. The thing is that every certain amount of lines I have a header. The sum of lines supposed to happen between two headers (in this case between `ITEM: ATOMS id mol element type x y z` and `ITEM: TIMESTEP`), add the number of lines to a list and read the next lines after next header and add the next sum to a list. I would like to consider the lines having regex:
`re.search(r"\d+\s\d+\s[N]\s[1]\s\d+.\d+\s\d+.\d+\s\d+.\d+")`

File example:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
38873
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
5.7248792664789718e+00 8.8775120733336294e+01
5.7248792664789718e+00 8.8775120733336294e+01
5.7248792664789718e+00 8.8775120733336294e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id mol element type x y z
1 1 N 1 36.8189 69.7138 60.6542
2 1 H 2 37.1158 70.7384 60.4896
3 1 H 2 36.2448 69.5936 61.4754
4 1 C 3 37.692 68.7914 60.2942
5 1 C 4 37.5524 67.3932 60.6119
ITEM: TIMESTEP
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
38873
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
5.7248792664789718e+00 8.8775120733336294e+01
5.7248792664789718e+00 8.8775120733336294e+01
5.7248792664789718e+00 8.8775120733336294e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id mol element type x y z
1 1 N 1 36.8189 69.7138 60.6542
2 1 H 2 37.1158 70.7384 60.4896
3 1 N 1 36.2448 69.5936 61.4754
4 1 N 1 37.692 68.7914 60.2942
5 1 C 4 37.5524 67.3932 60.6119
```

Result:
`N_list = [1, 3]`

Comment: Your question could be enhanced by showing what the output should look like for the input data you've shown

Comment: I gave a result what list I would like to get N_list = [1, 3]

Comment: In that case your description makes no sense at all. There is no summation in your output. EDIT: I get it now. You want to count the number of Ns in each segment

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the requirement is to count the number of N (element) values in each section of the file bounded by "ITEM: ATOMS" and "ITEM: TIMESTEP"

If that's the case then:

```
INPUT_FILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt'

interesting = False

output = []

with open(INPUT_FILE) as data:
    for line in data:
        if len(tokens := line.split()) > 1 and tokens[0] == 'ITEM:':
            match tokens[1]:
                case 'ATOMS':
                    interesting = True
                    output.append(0)
                case 'TIMESTEP':
                    interesting = False
        elif interesting and tokens[2] == 'N':
            output[-1] += 1

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however on my original file it does not work well - but I get the idea. Is it possible to do it with a regex I gave?

Comment: @kata248 If your original file looks like that shown in your question then it **will** work